# EntityFramework 6 Repository Pattern Preserving Relationships

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, code-first, entity-framework-6

I would like to create a Repository Pattern around EF6 code first.  I believe I need to work with Detached entities as saving a particular entity should not impact any other entity.  Something to the effect of:

```
    public void Create(T item)
    {
        _ctx.Entity.Add(item);
        _ctx.SaveChanges();
        _ctx.Entry(item).State = EntityState.Detached;
    }

    public void Update(T item)
    {
        _ctx.Entity.Attach(item);                    
        _ctx.Entry(item).State = EntityState.Modified;
        _ctx.SaveChanges();
        _ctx.Entry(item).State = EntityState.Detached;
    }

    public void Delete(T item)
    {
        _ctx.Entity.Attach(item);
        _ctx.Entity.Remove(item);
        _ctx.SaveChanges();
    }
```

My test POCOS are

```
public class Foo { 
  public int Id { get; set; } 
  public string Name { get; set; } 
  public virtual ICollection<Bar> Bars { get; set; } 
} 
 public class Bar { 
 public int Id { get; set; } 
 [Required] 
 public Foo Foo { get; set; } 
 public string Name { get; set; } 
}
```

Is there an accepted practice for this?  In the above code, for examples, if T item has a child collection and I add an element to that collection and update, the element will not get added and I seem to run into

> "An error occurred while saving entities that do not expose foreign
>   key properties for their relationships"

errors on delete.

Thanks!

Comment: post the error and related Pocos. Or relevant poco parts.

Comment: My test POCOS are  

    `public class Foo  
    {  
        public int Id { get; set; }  
        public string Name { get; set; }  
        public virtual ICollection<Bar> Bars { get; set; }  
    }  
  
    public class Bar  
    {  
        public int Id { get; set; }  
        [Required]  
        public Foo Foo { get; set; }  
        public string Name { get; set; }  
    }  

The error is stated above